# How to see the number of used observations to train a model?

Tags: r

Say I have a linear model in R. Using the model object, how can I see the number of observations used to train that model ?

For example

```
library(ISLR)
lm.fit <- lm(mpg ~ acceleration + weight + horsepower + displacement, data = Auto)
lm.fit
```

How to see the number of observations used to train the model `lm.fit`?

In this example I obviously have access to the `Auto` data frame and could look at its rows with `nrow(Auto)`. However, once you use the differing training and test sets, it becomes less obvious. I would like to make sure that the expected number of observations were used to train a model with just using the model object.

Comment: All the data will be used to train the model. If you don't want all the data to be used as training data, you will have to slice the data yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the number of the fitted values.

```
length(lm.fit$fitted.values)
# [1] 392
```

Check:

```
dim(Auto)
# [1] 392   9
```